# Rails - Inject method name and Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

Can anybody explain to me why when monkey patching the Hash class and adding a method called "inject" for a Rails project, the session just breaks? cookie is empty and even without a session name. Rails 5. I've just changed the method name and it works. But if someone have got into a similar situation or knows exactly why, it would be nice to learn a new thing! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting [Enumerable#inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Which is one of the many reasons to not modify built in classes.

Answer (score 1):

`Hash` haven't `inject` normally -- it is just inherited from `Enumerable#inject`.

So when you monkey patch it, of course you can break it.

For example cookies use [this method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L446-L457) in Rails.